# Cypher query to find nodes that have 3 relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I figured out how to write this query when I am looking for 2 relationships, but not sure how to add more relationships to the query.

Assume you have a book club database with 'reader' and 'book' as nodes.  The 'book' nodes have a 'genre' attribute (to define that the book is a Fiction, Non-Fiction, Biography, Reference, etc.)  There is a Relationship "HasRead" between 'reader' nodes and 'book' nodes where someone has read a particular book.

If I want to find readers that have read both Fiction **AND** Non-Fiction books, I could execute this Cypher query:

```
Start b1=node:MyBookIndex('Genre:Fiction'), 
      b2=node:MyBookIndex('Genre:Non-Fiction')
Match b1-[:HadRead]-r-[:HasRead]-b2
Return r.ReaderName
```

The key to the above query is the Match clause that has the two book aliases feeding into the `r` alias for the 'reader' nodes.

Question: How would I write the query to find users that have read Fiction **AND** Non-Fiction **AND** Reference books?  I'm stuck with how you would write the Match clause when you have more than 2 things you are looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can have multiple line specified in a single `MATCH` clause, separated by commas. For example, the following two `MATCH` clauses are semantically equivalent (and will be evaluated identically by the engine):

```
//these mean the same thing!
match a--b--c
match a--b, b--c
```

You can have any number of these matches. So, plugging that into your query, you get this:

```
start b1=node:MyBookIndex('Genre:Fiction'), 
      b2=node:MyBookIndex('Genre:Non-Fiction'),
      b3=node:MyBookIndex('Genre:Reference')
match b1-[:HasRead]-r,
      b2-[:HasRead]-r,
      b3-[:HasRead]-r
return r.ReaderName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user cypher '*with*' clause -

```
start b1=node:MyBookIndex('Genre:Fiction'), 
      b2=node:MyBookIndex('Genre:Non-Fiction'),
      b3=node:MyBookIndex('Genre:Reference')
match b1-[:HasRead]-r-[:HasRead]-b2
with b3, r
match b3-[:HasRead]-r
return r.ReaderName
```

Comment: One problem with using `WITH` in this case is that you're forcing neo4j to completely enumerate the first batch of `r`s before continuing to filter out the ones that don't have a relationship to `b3`. The performance may or may not be important in this particular case, but in general it is better to use multiple `MATCH`es.

Comment: @ean5533 not really sure whether performance will be impacted, don't know how neo4j processes this under the hood, but yes using multiple matches definitely looks cleaner. +1 !

Comment: I have read about the WITH clause elsewhere and the powerful flexibility it offers similar to the UNIX pipe command.  For my purpose here though, I am going to stick with @Gopi's suggestion as I find it a more readable/easier to understand syntax.